# How can I configure glass fish to use application managed entity managers?

Tags: spring, transactions, glassfish

How can I configure glass fish to use application managed entity managers? I get the following error with the configuration given below.

I do not want glassfish to manage transactions, I want to only use spring managed transactions with RESOURCE_LOCAL setting, not JTA,  in the persistence unit

```
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : The persistence-context-ref-name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean/entityManager] .... resolves to a persistence unit called [spring-jpa] which is of type RESOURCE_LOCAL. Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager. Please verify your application.
```

My Cofiguration:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="spring-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>mysql/mydb</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.myproject"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="dataSource"
       //....
    </bean>    
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="spring-jpa" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
          <!--  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">-->
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [this forum post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58527-transaction-type-quot-JTA-quot-quot-RESOURCE_LOCAL-quot), I quote:

> In a Java EE environment, if this element [transaction-type] is not
>   speciﬁed, the default is JTA. In a Java SE environment, if this
>   element is not speciﬁed, a default of RESOURCE_LOCAL may be assumed.

So, in your configuration try:

```
<persistence-unit name="spring-jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
```